# Find pattern in string of numbers

Tags: algorithm

I'm not sure how to google this, but I'm sure there is already a solution out there in some form somewhere. Here is my problem:

I have a string of numbers composed of integers ranging from 0 - 6. A zero represents a failure, and anything other than zero represents a success. A one represents the lowest degree of success, and a six represents a higher degree of success. Ones are more common than twos, twos more common than threes, and so on. The distribution between zeros and non-zeros is roughly 50/50 with sixes representing only about 1% of the result set. An example: 000100112000300151011121

There could be thousands of numbers in a string. I'd like to develop an algorithm that would analyze the string and search for patterns that could give clues to when the next number will be something other than zero, and secondly a pattern that could give away when there is a higher chance of getting a number greater than 1. Is anyone familiar with something in existence or could someone point me in a direction to research? Thanks.

Comment: [Bayesian Inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference) sounds like exactly what you need.

Comment: Does the sequence prior to a given point influence the next value? A [hidden-markov model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model) might be what you want.

Comment: @Ian Mercer I'm not sure what influences the numbers. That's why I'm looking at trying to find a pattern to see if it truly is a randomized distribution. Edit: Ah, I think your question was rhetorical. I'll look at that one too. Thanks.

Comment: @Matt Thanks I'll take a look at it.